# can't connect to FTP server -- disconnects after FEAT command

Tags: networking, routing, ftp

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server of which I do not control.  WinSCP & FileZilla both do not connect.  Here is a scrubbed down log:

```
Status: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.0.1)
Command:    USER xxx
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I verified that the FEAT command is the issue, because I connected to the server using windows commandline ftp.exe, and after running `quote FEAT`, it would give me the same response:

```
211-Features:
```

...and then disconnects.

What exactly is happening here?  Also, since I do not control the FTP server, is there a way in either FileZilla or WinSCP to get around this (ie, keep them from sending the `FEAT` command after connection?)

***Update 1***

- I'm able to connect to other FTP servers fine -- just a problem with this particular server

***Update 2***
 - some more strangeness discovered.  Let me describe my setup a little more.  I am trying to connect from a laptop (dev A) (static IP address 192.168.1.2) that is connected wirelessly to another laptop running ICS (dev B) (wireless adapter has static IP address of 192.168.1.1, but it has an external IP address .
 - I have no issues connecting to the server from `dev B`. (FEAT command returns a valid response)
 - I have no issues connecting to OTHER FTP sites using `dev A` (FEAT command returns valid response)

So it can't be a firewall issue, since I'm able to connect to other sites fine with `dev A` -- but it can't be an issue with the particular FTP server because I can connect to it fine with `dev B`....??

This is a head scratcher... :(

Comment: Apart from the FEAT command, can you do anything at all before the disconnect? dir, cd, ls,....?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, I can do all basic operations using the ftp.exe windows commandline client.  I just can't use WinSCP or FileZilla since those programs issue a FEAT after authenticating.

Comment: As a followup question, does anyone know of any GUI FTP clients (Windows) that do NOT issue a FEAT command?

Comment: Increase Filezilla's debug output level (Edit->Settings->Debug) and perhaps you'll learn more about what's causing the disconnect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use Total Commander with this option, added to wcx_ftp.ini:

```
[General]
PreventFEAT=1
```

This will prevent using 211-Feature command. This is a bug of ICS mechanism in windows, not FileZilla or other ftp-clients or servers.

Comment: do you have any links documenting this ICS bug?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug in the FTP server. Please consult the system admin of the server.

Comment: sysadmin of the server (it's a big webhosting company) won't fix it because he says he can connect to it fine :(

Comment: Try increasing your TTL limit.

Comment: can you provide additional information on why you think this error is happening, and reasoning for your suggestions?  I am not only looking for a solution, but also trying to understand what exactly is happening.